# Final object and existence of fiber-product implies the existence of finite projective limits

Tags: category-theory

This is exercise 4.3 of Görtz/Wedhorn: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category in which a final object and fiber products exist. Show that in $\mathcal{C}$ finite projective limits exist.

My thoughts: because of the final object we have the existence of finite products. Now assume we have a category $\mathcal{I}$ with finitely many objects and finite Hom-sets (is this the correct interpretation of "finite projective limit"?) and a functor $F:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ over whom we want to take the projective limit. Fot this, I thought of starting with the product $P=\prod_{i\in \mathcal{I}}F(i)$ and then for a morphism $u:i\rightarrow j$ we take the fiber product $C_1:=P\times_{F(j)}F(i)$ with respect to $F(u)$ and the projection. Doing this inductively for all such morphisms and replacing $P$ by an appropriate step of our sequence $C_k$, we finally stop at some $C_n$ after we used all morphisms. Does this yield a projective limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption of finite hom-sets is not the correct interpration. Finite (co)limits simply means the diagram is indexed by a finite category. The proof you are looking for relies on the elementary fact that all finite limits exist as soon as all finite products and equalisers exist. Dually, all finite colimits exist as soon as all finite coproducts and coequalisers exist. Terminal object + pullback yields binary products. Terminal object + binary products implies all finite products exist. The equaliser of a parallel pair can be constructed as their pullback. QED.

Comment: Finite limit simply means the diagram is indexed by a **finite** category.

Comment: Thank you @Jochen I fixed it.